# How can I make a pause function for WebClient()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, youtube, webclient, onpause

I'm making a YouTube Downloader, I've finished everything [ The application is completed now ] but this annoys me ;

How to make something can pause this downloader

```
try
{
    wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_DownloadProgressChanged);
    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadFileCompleted);
    CancelBtn.Enabled = true;
    wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(link), dwnFile);
    ResultLabel.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can directly. You might need to do it manually somehow.

Comment: Are you looking for something like a restartable downloader, or do you just want to pause for a few seconds, keeping the connection open so you can un-pause and continue?

Answer (score 2):

You can't if you wish to continue using `WebClient`; otherwise you'll need to use a method that gives you more control over the streaming of bytes, such as a `WebRequest` (of which you can manage the response stream) or sockets.